# Memory Leak in CGMutablePathRef

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am drawing a line on every update in a SKScene. However, eventually despite me releasing the line with each create, the application still crashes. I used to just keep a CGMutablePathRef as an instance variable, and released it when it got too big. I changed it in favor for the mutable array because I thought it would fix the memory problem. It does not.

Any ideas? This function is the only place where I am creating and releasing

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    if (![_currentlyRunning isEqual:@""] && canMove && !_dead) {
        if (!linePoints) {
            linePoints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        [linePoints enqueue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(_robot.position.x, _robot.position.y)]];
        if ([linePoints count] > 200) [linePoints dequeue];
    }
    if (linePoints) {
        CGMutablePathRef line = CGPathCreateMutable();

        for(int i = 0; i < [linePoints count]; ++i) {
            CGPoint p = [linePoints[i] CGPointValue];
            if(i == 0) {
                CGPathMoveToPoint(line, NULL, p.x, p.y);
            } else {
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(line, NULL, p.x, p.y);
            }
        }
        [lineLayer removeFromParent];
        lineLayer = nil;
        lineLayer = [SKShapeNode node];
        lineLayer.path = line;
        CGPathRelease(line);
        lineLayer.lineWidth = 7;
        lineLayer.alpha = .2;
        [lineLayer setStrokeColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [self addChild:lineLayer];
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that the crash means that you have a memory problem? Post your crash log, call stack and highlight the line where it crashes. Add an exception breakpoint to find out.

Comment: I forgot to mention, but I assumed it was implicit. I get the memory warnings right before I crash. It was also the only thing I added to the code, which was working perfectly before. My solution was to make it draw the 200 point line less frequently. It seems to have done the trick. Perhaps the garbage collector can't keep up with the memory allocation? Not sure if that's even a thing.

Comment: well it would be kinda weird if a "few hundred bytes" structure like CGPath would cause memory issues - it can but it would take a **lot** of them leaking. Check with Instruments (and an analyze build), I wouldn't be surprised if you found other, more serious memory leaks. Also check if you aren't simply loading too many resources overall, a common misunderstanding being that image file size equals texture memory usage.

Comment: You don't think it could simply be the method update being called 60 times a second? Like I said, I have had zero memory issues before the addition of the line code in update.

Comment: What does Instruments say?

Comment: It was a lot of 16byte allocations under (I don't remember now, but it was the untitled category?) that was increasing at the rate of ~1mb/10s.

Comment: I changed the frequency with which the line was drawn (it didn't need to be drawn 60 times/s), and now there are no leaks. I do however find it hard to believe that I was creating memory too fast for garbage collector to delete. It's not even garbage collector if I'm calling CGPathRelease(line); right?